Cannot get response from an API call in the express.js backend
I want to make an API call from my backend server running express.js. I expect when I visit http://localhost:3004/api/weather?city=[cityName], I should see the json response from openweathermap.org.
Instead, I get the message "unknown endpoint" from my middleware. Thats the terminal output from the server:
Time: 2024-09-08T08:02:14.510Z
Method: GET
Path:   /api/weather
Query:  { city: 'zagreb' }
Headers: {
  host: 'localhost:3004',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  pragma: 'no-cache',
  'cache-control': 'no-cache',
  'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="128", "Not;A=Brand";v="24", "Google Chrome";v="128"',
  'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
  'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"macOS"',
  'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/128.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
  accept: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7',
  'sec-fetch-site': 'none',
  'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
  'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
  'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br, zstd',
  'accept-language': 'en,de-DE;q=0.9,de;q=0.8,fr-FR;q=0.7,fr;q=0.6,en-US;q=0.5,hr;q=0.4,nl;q=0.3',
  cookie: 'Webstorm-8aead92d=3b86ad4a-0728-412a-9b16-792fba3736a2'
}
Body:   {}
IP:     ::1

Here is my code for the Route:
require('dotenv').config()
const weatherRouter = require('express').Router()
const axios = require('axios')

const apiKey = process.env.API_KEY

weatherRouter.get('/api/weather', async (req, res, next) => {
    const { city } = req.query
    if (!city) {
        return res.status(400).json({ error: 'City must be provided' });
    }
    try {
        console.log(`Fetching weather data for ${city}`);
        const response = await axios.get(`http://api.openweathermap.org/geo/1.0/direct?q=${city}&limit=5&appid=${apiKey}`);
        res.json(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to fetch weather data' });
    }
    next()
})

module.exports = weatherRouter

The final goal is, that I make the request from a form from the frontend running react.js. This currently does not work either.
That is the code I wrote on the frontend to link it to with be backend:
import axios from 'axios'
const baseUrl = '/api/weather'

const getWeatherData = async city => {
    const response = await axios.get(`${baseUrl}?city=${city}`)
    return response.data
}

export default { getWeatherData }

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?
Here is the code from app.js where I mount the routes:
const config = require('./utils/config')
const express = require('express')
require('express-async-errors')
const app = express()
const cors = require('cors')
const citiesRouter = require('./controllers/cities')
const weathersRouter = require('./controllers/weathers')
/* const usersRouter = require('./controllers/users')
const loginRouter = require('./controllers/login') */
const middleware = require('./utils/middleware')
const logger = require('./utils/logger')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

mongoose.set('strictQuery', false)

logger.info('connecting to', config.MONGODB_URI)

mongoose.connect(config.MONGODB_URI)
  .then(() => {
    logger.info('connected to MongoDB')
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    logger.error('error connection to MongoDB:', error.message)
  })

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.static('dist'))
app.use(express.json())
app.use(middleware.requestLogger)
app.use(middleware.tokenExtractor)

app.use('/api/cities', citiesRouter)
app.use('/api/weather', weathersRouter)

app.use(middleware.unknownEndpoint)
app.use(middleware.errorHandler)

module.exports = app

Here is the code from vite.config.js:
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  proxy: {
    "/api": {
      target: "http://localhost:3004",
      changeOrigin: true,
    },
  },
})


Here is a screenshot when making a get request from the frontend:

Here is a screenshot after removing the proxy in vite.config.js and setting baseURL to http://localhost:3004/api/weather:


show the code where you're mounting weatherRouter

Reedited my initial post

Full example BE and FE:
// index.js
const express = require('express');
const weatherRouter = require('./routes/weatherRouter'); // Import the weatherRouter

const app = express();
const port = 3004;

// Middleware to parse JSON
app.use(express.json());

// Use the weatherRouter for '/api/weather' routes
app.use('/api/weather', weatherRouter);

// Root route
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Welcome to the Express App!');
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${port}`);
});

weatherRouter
// routes/weatherRoutter.js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

// A simple weather route
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.json({
    location: 'New York',
    temperature: '22°C',
    condition: 'Sunny',
  });
});

module.exports = router;

Frontend code:
vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'http://localhost:3004',
        changeOrigin: true,
      },
    },
  },
});

api.js
import axios from 'axios';

const axiosClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: import.meta.env.VITE_API_BASE_URL || '',
});

const getWeatherData = async (city) => {
  const response = await axiosClient.get('/api/weather', {
    params: {
      city,
    },
  });
  return response.data;
};

export default { getWeatherData };

App.jsx
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import api from './api';

function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    api.getWeatherData('New York').then((data) => console.log(data));
  }, []);

  return <div>Test</div>;
}

export default App;




Hey, now it works. I have to tell you that dont have much experience in web dev yet, so thank you so much for your effort. There is a minor issue: Now the url has /api twice.

remove rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^/api/, '')

const axiosClient = axios.create({
baseURL: import.meta.env.VITE_API_BASE_URL || '',
});

make these changes to avoid api tiwce

Great, thank you so much again. Now I need a break

In the router, change route from:
weatherRouter.get('/api/weather', async (req, res, next) => {

to
weatherRouter.get('/', async (req, res, next) => {

as you're already using that route when mounting the router here:
app.use('/api/weather', weathersRouter)


Your provided solution works. Thank you for your help. Now I can continue working on my project. But I would like to know if its better to define 'api/weather' in the router or where I mount it?

Sorry, I did not test if the request works from the frontend. It does not. I provided a screenshot.

as now the backend works, it's probably something with proxy on frontend..

what if you set /api/weather to proxy

I also having an error in the terminal: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

when does that happen, after of before you changing the proxy path..?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Updated:
weatherRouter.get('/')

Yes, correct I missed that from your post.
Fix your baseURL in case you use vite proxy and also better use env var for production.
const axiosClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: import.meta.env.VITE_API_BASE_URL || ''
});


const getWeatherData = async (city) => {
  const response = await axiosClient.get('/api/weather', {
    params: {
      city,
    },
  });
  return response.data;
};

And also remove next() in your request handler on BE. You already send response from request handler for all cases but because of next() call some of your middlewares that goes next after app.use('/api/weather', weathersRouter) try to send response again. That's why you are getting Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client.

I setup a proxy in vite.config.js. I will post it.

In that case open network tab in the browser and check on what url FE sends request.

Recheck my answer there should be /api in baseURL and /api in api call. Because /api = http://localhost:3004 but also your endpoint url starts with /api

The backend server listens on port 3004: Server running on port 3004
connected to MongoDB

Change your FE code to solution from my post. After that check a network tab again

I did, but it is still the same as in the screenshot I have posted already.

Upvote please it's correct
